# Store data from JavaScript object to custom table in user account

Tags: php, javascript, users, user-meta

When a user is logged into WordPress, I want to be able to store data coming from a JS query into a custom table of the user in WordPress.

I want to show this data when the user goes to their user page.

For example:

1. User is logged in and runs a search query using form on website.
   [image]
2. In the console, I `console.log(data.searchData.pickup.location);` This returns 'Amsterdam - Airport - Schiphol'.
3. I want to send this record to a Wordpress table of the logged in user. I guess I might have to create the table first?
4. When user goes to 'My account' page, user can see that he ran this query in the past.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: you can save data on user level with the function `add_user_meta` : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

Comment: Than you for your answer, but how to send the JS data to that php function?

Comment: save the data on the same time that the user sends the form. maybe you don't need JavaScript to do that.